# select mongodb database from config file for symfony2

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony

I'm trying to connect to two mongodb databases with symfony2, when I tried one database it worked well, but with two I have an error, here is my config.yml file:

```
doctrine_mongodb:
connections:
    statistiques:
        server: mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/statistiques
        options: 
            db: statistiques

    archive_prod:
        server: mongodb://user:pass@localhost:27017/archive_prod
        options: 
            db: archive_prod

document_managers:
    statistiques:
        auto_mapping: true
        connection: statistiques

    archive_prod:
        auto_mapping: true
        connection: archive_prod
```

In the error I have this:
Failed to connect to: localhost:27017: Authentication failed on database 'default' with username 'user': auth fails

even if I didn't select any database with the name 'default'
I can set default database with: default_database: statistiques
but I need to use two databases

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the documentation

http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html#multiple-connections

Comment: Would be good if you explained how you fixed it in an answer ;)